# How to stop double canDeactivate call when redirecting in target route guard?

Tags: angular

I need to add `canDeactivate` guard to one of my app routes. In that function I call native `confirm` function in order to confirm whether the user really wants to leave the page. If users goes to non guard protected route is all seems fine.

There's a problem however when users redirect to a route where there's a guard that redirect to another page. What is happening then is that confirm pop-up appears twice.

I've created a simple reproduction. https://stackblitz.com/edit/can-activate-deactive-problem.

1. Click on the "Link to forbidden".
2. Click "ok"
3. Pop-up appears twice.

Is there any way to work around this problem without some hacky solutions?

*can-deactivate.guard.ts*

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<any> {
  canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return confirm('are you sure you want to leave?');
  }
}
```

*can-activate.guard.ts*

```js
export class CanActivateGuard implements CanActivateGuard {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    this.router.navigate(['/not-allowed']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's the "intended" behaviour apparently: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9530#issuecomment-228572000

Comment: Did anyone find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

We can maintain a flag indicating whether the confirmation pop-up has already been shown or not. The `confirmationShown` value needs to be reset to its default state after navigation. You can achieve this by subscribing to the `NavigationEnd` event in the `CanDeactivateGuard` and resetting the flag accordingly. Here is the working snippet [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/can-activate-deactive-problem-zdhaij?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcan-deactivate.guard.ts)

```
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<any> {
  private confirmationShown: boolean = false;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.confirmationShown = false;
      });
  }

  canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (!this.confirmationShown) {
      this.confirmationShown = true;
      return confirm('Are you sure you want to leave?');
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: what about unsubscribing router events inside a guard?

Answer (score 0):

Its a intended behaviour that canDeactivate will can twice. What can be done is discard the first call and return the result inside a promise

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
    export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<any> {
      isFirstEvent: boolean = true;

      canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          if (this.isFirstEvent) {
            resolve(true);
            this.isFirstEvent = false;
          }
          setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(confirm('are you sure you want to leave?'));
          }, 10)
        });
      }
    }
```